# The Adaptive card display is not displayed on the cortana channel but works well on teams and emulator

Tags: botframework, cortana, adaptive-cards, cortana-skills-kit

I have created a QnA bot and integrated cortana with it.
I am able to see hero cards on the cortana channel but not adaptive cards.
Though I get the attachment in my reply variable in my code, the card is not rendering.
Alse the speak property of adaptive card seems to be deprecated.

Below is the json response i get as debugging info

```
{
  "botId": "ValoremReplyCortanaBot",
  "botRequest": {
    "type": "message",
    "id": "ru2O3ASCqo",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-28T12:28:38.6194349Z",
    "serviceUrl": "https://CortanaBFChannelEastUs.azurewebsites.net/",
    "channelId": "cortana",
    "from": {
      "id": "6E45EE54844A79A85857DE2CEF10B9223A16AE6ACC2360DC007744F9CA7377E5"
    },
    "conversation": {
      "id": "f002bf89-2d89-4e41-a5b6-bcdfa4e35cc3"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "id": "valoremreplycortanabot"
    },
    "locale": "en-US",
    "text": "guide",
    "entities": [
      {
        "type": "Intent",
        "name": "None",
        "entities": []
      },
      {
        "type": "AuthorizationToken",
        "token": "##",
        "status": 0
      },
      {
        "type": "UserInfo",
        "current_location": {
          "StartTime": "2019-05-28T12:28:38.0673147Z",
          "EndTime": null,
          "Hub": {
            "Id": null,
            "Type": "Other",
            "Name": null,
            "Latitude": 10.0126075744629,
            "Longitude": 76.3658599853516,
            "Address": null
          },
          "VenueName": null,
          "Away": false
        },
        "name": {
          "GivenName": "##",
          "FamilyName": "##"
        },
        "email": "##@outlook.com"
      },
      {
        "type": "DeviceInfo",
        "supportsDisplay": "true"
      }
    ],
    "channelData": {
      "skillId": "cc3ef598-4f4f-444f-bd20-87a211581607",
      "skillProductId": "188779dd-2894-4cb3-b93f-b99955039ead",
      "isDebug": true
    }
  },
  "botResponse": {
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-28T12:28:51.306281Z",
    "serviceUrl": "https://CortanaBFChannelEastUs.azurewebsites.net/",
    "channelId": "cortana",
    "from": {
      "id": "valoremreplycortanabot"
    },
    "conversation": {
      "id": "f002bf89-2d89-4e41-a5b6-bcdfa4e35cc3"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "id": "6E45EE54844A79A85857DE2CEF10B9223A16AE6ACC2360DC007744F9CA7377E5"
    },
    "locale": "en-US",
    "text": "",
    "attachments": [
      {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "content": {
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "version": "1.0",
          "body": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "size": "large",
              "weight": "bolder"
            },
            {
              "type": "Image",
              "size": "stretch",
              "url": "##",
              "width": "100px",
              "height": "100px"
            }
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
              "url": "##",
              "title": "Guide Poster",
              "speak": "Guide Poster"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "entities": [],
    "replyToId": "ru2O3ASCqo"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML renderer inside Cortana desktop is less forgiving than other clients. Check https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/TextBlock.html

To make sure every element has its REQUIRED fields.

It could be as simple as your TextBlock not having a text object....  Add
`"text": ""`

Oh, and speak isn't deprecated.  It is at a card level; peer to body.  And... Cortana won't speak it by default. You need to copy it from the card and add it to the message https://github.com/microsoft/cortana-skills-samples/blob/master/Consumer/CSharp/V4Patches/07.using-adaptive-cards.diff

Comment: Thank you, making sure that all the required fields have some value worked for me.

Comment: var cardContent = CardMaker.SubstituteAdaptiveCard(qnaAnswer.title, qnaAnswer.subtitle, null, cardImages, cardActions);
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
                    {
                        ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                        Content = cardContent
                    };

                    **string speak = (string)((JObject)attachment.Content).SelectToken("speak");**  

The bold part is giving me the error that "Unable to cast object of type 'AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'."

Comment: Re your current cast bug, its because you are using a different "proxy" object to implement adaptive cards then the example.  Create this as a new question? The proxy classes likely have a better way at getting the speak property.  I am using 1.0.6 (I think).